# How to Create Jenkins Input thats no blocking, and based on previous command output

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I have 2 issues, that are both part of the same problem.  I am running terraform inside a JenkinsFile, this is all happening on a docker container that runs on a specific node.  I have a few different environments with the ec2_plugin, that are labeled  'environment_ec2'.  Its done this way since we use ansible, and I want to be able to execute ansible locally in the VPC.

1) How do you create an input and stage that are only executed if a previous command returns a specific output?

2) How can I make this non blocking?

```
node('cicd_ec2') {
    stage('Prepare Environment'){
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
    }

    withAWSParameterStore(credentialsId: 'jenkin_cicd', naming: 'relative', path: '/secrets/cicd/', recursive: true, regionName: 'us-east-1') {
        docker.image('jseiser/jenkins_devops:0.7').inside {
            stage('Configure Git Access') {
                sh 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'
                sh 'mv config ~/.ssh/config'
                sh 'chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config'
                sh "echo '$BITBUCKET_CLOUD' > ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa"
                sh 'chmod 600 ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa'
                sh "echo '$CICD_CODE_COMMIT_KEY' > ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa"
                sh 'chmod 600 ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa'
                sh "echo '$IDAUTO_CICD_MGMT_PEM' > ~/.ssh/idauto-cicd-mgmt.pem"
                sh 'chmod 600 ~/.ssh/idauto-cicd-mgmt.pem'
                sh 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
                sh 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
            }

            stage('Terraform'){
                sh './init-ci.sh'
                sh 'terraform validate'
                sh 'terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -out=create.tfplan'
            }

            input 'Deploy stack?'

            stage ('Terraform Apply') {
                sh 'terraform apply -no-color create.tfplan'
            }

            stage('Ansible'){
                sh 'ansible-galaxy -vvv install -r requirements.yml'
                sh 'ansible-playbook -i ~/ vpn.yml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only want to run the input and terraform apply, if the result of the below command is == 2.

```
terraform plan -detailed-exitcode
```

Since this all has to run on a ec2 instance, and it all has to use this container, I am not sure how I can do this input outside of a node like its recommended.  Since if the input sits long enough, this instance may go down and the rest of the code would be run on a new instance/workspace and the information I need from the git repo's and the terraform plan would not be present.  The git repo that I checkout contains the terraform configurations, the ansible configurations, and some configuration for SSH so that terraform and ansible are able to pull in their modules/roles from private git repos. The 'create.tfplan' that I would need to use IF terraform has a change would also need to be passed around.

Just really confused how I can get a good input, only get that input if I really need to run terraform apply, and how I can make it non blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to adopt this from my work-in-progess which is based on declarative pipeline, but I hope it still mostly works..

```java
def tfPlanExitCode

node {
  stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Plan') {
    tfPlanExitCode = sh('terraform plan -out=create.tfplan -detailed-exitcode', [returnStatus: true])
    stash 'workspace'
  }
}

if (tfPlanExitCode == "2") {
  input('Deploy stack?')

  stage('Apply') {
    node {
      unstash 'workspace'
      sh 'terraform apply -no-color create.tfplan'
    }
  }
}
```

The building blocks are:

- don't allocate an executor while the *input* is waiting (for hours..)
- stash your workspace contents (you can optionally specify which files to copy) and unstash later on the agent that continues the build

The visualization might be a bit screwed up, when some builds have the *Apply* stage and some don't. That's why I'm using the declarative pipelines, which allows to nicely/explicitly skip stages.